# Rails find_by_sql - how to run generic queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, finder-sql

I need to execute this query to find out the next auto_increment value that will be used by MySQL for a particular table.

```
find_by_sql ["select auto_increment from information_schema.tables where   
table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and auto_increment is not null", db_name, tbl_name]
```

How to invoke this particular query? This works on any model that I invoke it with returning an array of size 1 containing the object of the model. Edit: The object contains a hash named attributes which contains the auto_increment value as desired.

Are there any other ways to run such generic queries ? Would like to know if a change in the whole approach of using find_by_sql is possible to solve the original problem as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to run raw SQL without involving a model, you can obtain the [`connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-connection) directly and call one of the `select_*` methods ([`select_value`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_value) in this case). These methods just take a SQL statement as a string, so you can call [`sanitize_sql_array`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_array) to transform your parameters array (note that `sanitize_sql_array` is protected, so `send` may be required).

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value(
  ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, 
   ["select auto_increment from information_schema.tables where
    table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and auto_increment is not null", 
    db_name, tbl_name]))
```

The result returned will be a string.

Answer (score 0):

So that array containing one object of the model is actually ActiveRecord trying to convert the results of your query into an object.

Take a look at the #columns [edit: err "attributes"] attribute of that object and see where ActiveRecord has put the result you're looking for (I suspect it will be under a column named auto_increment)

Comment: @Ryan: Correct. I know the way to get the necessary output from the query. What I am asking is whether the whole approach of calling this query on a particular model is right and if there is any other way to invoke the method. Thanks!